# how to make a fault message and send it to a jms provider

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'am evaluating WSO2 esb and try this simple use case :

jms -> (esb) -> WebService (HelloService on WSO2 Application Server)
Send ws response to jms queue (end point EPQ_ESB_OUT)
Send fault to jms queue (end point EPQ_ESB_ERR)

When I stop WSO2 Application Server, the fault sequence is called and a message is sent to EPQ_ESB_ERR but the message is always empty...

I've tried to use makefault and buildfactory mediators but it fails in both case (empty message in both case).

My Proxy :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Test04Proxy02" transports="jms" startOnLoad="true" trace="enable">
    <target>
        <endpoint key="EPW_HelloService"/>
        <inSequence>
            <log>
                <property name="STEP" value="==== INseq"/>
            </log>      
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
            <log>
                <property name="STEP" value="==== OUTseq"/>
            </log>       
            <send>
                <endpoint key="EPQ_ESB_OUT"/>
            </send>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="full">
                <property name="STEP" value="==== FAULTseq"/>
                <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
                <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
                <property name="ERROR_DETAIL" expression="get-property('ERROR_DETAIL')"/>
            </log>       
            <payloadFactory>
                <format>
                    <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://myns">$1</ns:text>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg xmlns:ns="http://myns"
                                evaluator="xml"
                                expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="EPQ_ESB_ERR"/>
            </send>
        </faultSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:
Maybe you are having some issues with namesspaces. WSO seems to use the `ns` namespace itself extensively, so I would try using a different namespace in your payload factory, eg

```
       <payloadFactory>
            <format>
                <myns:text xmlns:myns="http://myns">$1</myns:text>
            </format>
            <args>
                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
```

(you shouldn't actually need a namespace definition in the `<arg>` element)

Comment: still empty msg in queue either by changing namespace or no namespace at all.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved :

Replaced ... by

```
<makefault version="soap11">
    <code expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
    <reason expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
</makefault>
```

and added

```
<parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
    <rules>         
        <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>         
        <default>application/xml</default>      
    </rules>
</parameter>
```

just before the  end tag.

Don't really know why it works now with this parameter...